# What am i doing wrong with my code? did i break it?

Tags: java

This is supposed to take the user input and print it backwards. I'm required to use a for-loop and length and use only the main class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("give me your name bruh");
    Scanner kbReader= new Scanner(System.in);
    String noobish=kbReader.next;
    int noob=noobish.length;

    for(int noob;noob >0;noob--){
      Char n= noobish.charAt(noobish);
      System.out.println(n);   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the curly bracket at the end of the for-loop code(for(int noob;noob >0;noob--)) on that line instead of before it.

Comment: Also remove `int` from `for(int noob;...` or better yet move your `int noob =...` declaration there instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that one.

Comment: Presumably the compiler complains that you use uninitialized variable `noob`.  That would be because the `noob` you declare inside the `for` loop is a different variable than the one declared outside it.

Comment: Well, the code you posted won't even compile. I'm going to say yes you did break it.

Comment: You'd also want to initialize noob to noobish.length-1, and run it as long as noob >= 0.

Comment: `kbReader.next()`  ....   `noobish.length()` ... You are missing the parentheses. Also, in the for-loop, remove the `int` from `int noob`.

Comment: Main.java:10: error: not a statement
    
for(noob;noob >0;noob--)

        ^
Main.java:11: error: variable declaration not allowed here

   
 Char n= noobish.charAt(noobish);

         ^
2 errors


exit status 1

Comment: ok i got some new code. problem is at the char statement. running java 8 on repl.it.

Comment: import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("give me your name bruh");
    Scanner kbReader= new Scanner(System.in);
    String noobish=kbReader.nextLine();
    int noob=noobish.length();
    System.out.println(noobish);
    System.out.println(noob);
    for (int k=noob;k>=0;k--)
    {
    System.out.println(noob);
    //char n=noobish.charAt(k);
    //System.out.print(n);   
    }
  }
}

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. And the error you are getting is `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Java8 has nothing to do with this. See @DaveK's answer

Answer (score 1):

Noob should be noobish.length-1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("give me your name bruh");
    Scanner kbReader= new Scanner(System.in);
    String noobish=kbReader.next();
    for(int noob = noobish.length-1;noob >= 0;noob--) {
        Char n= noobish.charAt(noob);
        System.out.println(n);   
    }
}
```